# Why is Prisma Migrate detecting a drift and explaining it as foreign keys were removed and then the same foreign keys were added again?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, prisma

I have an ongoing web app project on a NextJS prisma MySQL 8 stack hosted on Heroku. It's been running smoothly in production for about 6 months. At the end of 2023, my MySQL 5.6 DB hosting plan was being retired and I was forced to change plans and upgrade to MySQL 8, restoring my DB from a mysqldump.
Now when I run npx prisma migrate dev I am getting the following error:

```
Drift detected: Your database schema is not in sync with your migration history.

The following is a summary of the differences between the expected database schema given your migrations files, and the actual schema of the database.

It should be understood as the set of changes to get from the expected schema to the actual schema.

[*] Changed the `group` table
  [-] Removed foreign key on columns (createdById)
  [+] Added foreign key on columns (createdById)

[*] Changed the `groupmember` table
  [-] Removed foreign key on columns (groupId)
  [-] Removed foreign key on columns (userId)
  [+] Added foreign key on columns (groupId)
  [+] Added foreign key on columns (userId)
```

This makes no sense to me. It is describing the drift as "a foreign key was removed, then the same foreign key with the same name was added".
I am unable to use `prisma migrate resolve --applied` because all of my migrations have already been applied, and I cannot create a new migration because of this drift issue.